# How do you maintain an org development cycle with a B2B LEX store?

Tags: b2b-commerce, b2b-lex

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.b2b_comm_lex_comm_migrate_store.htm&type=5) for store migration in B2B LEX does not appear to let you properly use a 3-tier org development cycle; if you follow the directions to the letter you can end up with an Experience site added to your orgs divorced from the stores they are supposed to be associated with - and there is no way to change what Experience the store points to.

Is there any way to push Experiences in change sets in such a way to maintain this development cycle?  Otherwise it seems you'll have to manually make changes in each org every time you change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seemed to lie in [this old blog post](https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/05/10/deploying-a-salesforce-community-with-change-sets/) regarding communities, in which the Experience in both orgs - the source and target org - must have the same name.

In short, as far as B2B is concerned, follow the instructions in the migration documentation as linked in the original question, keeping these in mind:

- When you create the store in the target org, when prompted to make the Experience, make sure you give it the same name as the one in the source org
- If you have already created the store with a different name, simply change the name to match the source org's Experience.
- If you have an Experience with the same name source org's store Experience, but it is NOT connected to the store (ie. the Experience got moved over without a matching Experience to update for the store), rename it to something that doesn't match (eg. 'My Store Old') and follow the first two bullet points.

Now syncing should occur as expected using change sets.

In the [original discussion](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000BqY3xSAF) of this in the B2B Commerce Trailblazer group, Venkat Medapati of Salesforce had this to say:

> I understand the general concern here with migration in B2B context. We are working on a few improvements that will help with more seamless migration across environments in future.

> For now, you should look to first create a store (note store creation auto-creates an experience site mapped to the store automatically, so you can use the correct name working for both) and then plan to migrate the experience so that the Store-to-Experience mapping stays in tact. Ideally, you should combine that with rest of store metadata as Site/Storefront and Store are connected.

> If you try to migrate the experience site first, there could be issues with mapping after the fact, as you highlighted. Hope that helps! We will allow mapping store to an existing experience site in near future, I can confirm the timing in coming weeks (that should simplify this process further)

This method described is the way to go now, and there should hopefully be enhancements in future releases to better handle the disconnect.